# Will head() and tail() functions in R change the order of output?

Tags: r, tail, head

I know head() and tail() function will return the first or last parts of a dataset, but I wanna know if the two functions are gonna order the output, or just return without ordering them? Thanks many in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below, they do keep the original order:

```
df <- data.frame(number = 1:26, letter = letters[1:26])
```

```
> head(df)
  number letter
1      1      a
2      2      b
3      3      c
4      4      d
5      5      e
6      6      f
```

```
> tail(df)
   number letter
21     21      u
22     22      v
23     23      w
24     24      x
25     25      y
26     26      z
```

Comment: OK. I use this method and have a try. The two functions won't change the order. But actually I think your examples here are not so reasonable cuz df here is an orderly data frame itself. Thank you so much!